# Have there been any hints by writers about Blast?

Tags: one-punch-man

Blast is #1 among S-rating heroes; it is said that only Blast will be able to stop a God-level attack. However, we never actually see Blast, or get any hints as to who he/she may be.

The question is: has either ONE or Murata Yusuke hinted on who Blast might be?

Comment: Sorry but this is not a good type of question for this site. It invites lengthy lists of answers and broad discussion, which is more suitable for a forum than a Q&A site. But you might get what you're looking for on anime forums.

Comment: @Hakase  -  what if I just ask about official comments?

Comment: Sure, but you'll probably end up with no answers until the super obvious beyond any doubt info will appear in the upcoming season, and there won't be much use in asking coz everyone will know.

Comment: I'm talking about manga here; there's some hope in the light of current ark that maybe, just maybe, they'll have to deploy Blast. If there is one.

Comment: You have edited the question to seem less broad and I think it's actually alright now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blast appears during a certain, fairly recent (by chapter number) flashback in the webcomic.  The depiction is pretty fully detailed (full facial details are obscured, but it's more detailed than "vague shadowy outline"), and interacts with the character having the flashback.

> [image: blast during flashback]

His appearance seems vaguely similar to one or more characters in both the manga and webcomic, but for now that seems to be the only connection: vague superficial similarities--this particular style of face and hairdo seems to be common, and no one has ever appeared in this outfit before.